# texlive can not install PDF doc of clrscode3e

Tags: ieeetran, texlive-2018, clrscode3e

#### Update on May 11, 2019:

From the third item of the *Basic Requirements* section of TUG webpage [TeX Live package contributions](https://tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html#requirements), TeX Live

> must refrain from installing generated documentation when there is no source.

Therefore, the source-free doc of `clrscode` should not been included by TeX Live.

Up to now, TeX Live has distributed new versions of packages `clrscode` and `IEEEtran` with source-free docs being deleted, and being substituted by the special README.TEXLIVE file (as shown in @Ulrike Fischer's answer).

If anyone finds other similar violations, you can write to `tex-live@tug.org` directly.

#### Original Question:

On CTAN, the package [`clrscode3e`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/clrscode3e) has 3 files, a 75kB PDF documentation, an sty source code, and a README. But using `tlmgr`, I always can not install the PDF doc. (The package itself can be used and works all right.) The similar package `clrscode`, which also has 3 files (pdf + sty + README) on CTAN, can be installed from `tlmgr` with doc as expected.

I also find that my local file `clrscode3e.tlpobj`, located in `TEXMFDIST/../tlpkg/tlpobj/`, does not include the PDF doc under tag `docfiles`, compared to the similar file `clrscode.tlpobj`.

```
$ cat clrscode3e.tlpobj | grep -A 3 'docfiles'
docfiles size=2
 texmf-dist/doc/latex/clrscode3e/README details="Readme"
 texmf-dist/doc/latex/clrscode3e/README.TEXLIVE
runfiles size=4

$ cat clrscode.tlpobj | grep -A 3 'docfiles' 
docfiles size=11
 texmf-dist/doc/latex/clrscode/README
 texmf-dist/doc/latex/clrscode/clrscode.pdf details="Package documentation"
runfiles size=3
```

Also, the message received from `tlmgr info clrscode3e` shows the sizes of package `clrscode3e` are

```
doc: 9k, run: 17k
```

The sizes are so small that definitely no PDF docs is included.

---

How these differences are produced? And whom I can send feedback about "can not install PDF doc of clrscode3e" to, the maintainer of the package, the texlive team, or the CTAN team?

I am using

- macOS 10.14.2,
- TeX Live 2018, and
- tlmgr revision 49226 (2018-11-23 00:37:16 +0100)

Comment: On ctan there is only a pdf but no (tex-)source file and this means that texlive will not install it (some debian open source rule ...). You will have to copy it manually in your doc-folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [On ctan](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/clrscode3e) there are 3 files, a pdf, a sty, and a README. The package `clrscode` has exactly the same [3 files](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/clrscode) on ctan, but can be installed with doc successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXlive installs a readme and a readme.texlive in the doc-folder. The second readme says:

```
The following files have been removed in the TeX Live installation of
the current package, typically due to duplication, lack of space, or
missing source code.  You can find these files on CTAN at
        http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/clrscode3e
If questions or concerns, email tex-live@tug.org.

        clrscode3e.pdf
```

The pdf is not installed because of the missing source file.

Comment: I see. By saying "source file", it means the source file of the pdf doc. But the same condition holds for package `clrscode`. Why the pdf doc of `clrscode` can be installed?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: If texlive removed the pdf file of `clrscode3e` because missing source code, then texlive should removed the pdf file of `clrscode` (a different package which also does not upload the source code of pdf to ctan) too. But the fact is I can install `clrscode` with its pdf, but when I install `clrscode3e` its pdf is removed.

Comment: Ah. now I understand. Yes that looks like an error. If someone tells the texlive maintainer about it then they will probably remove the pdf from clrscode too.

Comment: To update some info: After contacted `tex-live@tug.org`, TeX Live now has deleted source-free docs in packages `clrscode` and `IEEEtran`. And authors of those packages are informed.